# Prevent Apache from writing to a file

Tags: php, apache-2.4, permissions, file-permissions

I have a website based on a CMS, running on Apache 2.4/PHP7.4. The CMS has an admin interface and changes you make there are written to config files inside the web root (/var/www/html/...). As a crude security measure, I thought I'd prevent writing to these files by changing file permission and ownership.

Apache runs as the `www-data` user, and the normal permissions for the files are `644 www-data:www-data`. If I `chmod` and `chown` the files to `444 otheruser:otheruser` and click "save" inside the CMS, the file is still written and it is also changed back to `644 www-data:www-data`.

The containing directory has `777 otheruser:otheruser` (for some reason). `otheruser` is member of the `sudo` group, if that somehow matters.

Is my approach doomed? What gives Apache/PHP the power to control these files regardless of ownership and permissions? Does it have to do with the fact that one of the many `apache2` processes runs as `root`?

Comment: 777 on the directory means that anyone can remove and recreate any files from that directory regardless of the permissions of the file itself.

Comment: Oh, seems I've missed something fundamental regarding how permissions work. Thanks @AlexD!